# How to reduce number of sub-folders in MVC Areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, directory, areas

I have an asp.net MVC3 application, and I'm using Areas.

By default, I understand the setup would look like this:

```
Areas\
   Orders\
       Controllers\
           HomeController.cs     (Action method: Index)
           OrderController.cs   (Action method: OrderIndex)
           TransferController.cs (Action method: TransferIndex)
       Views\
           Home\
               Index.aspx
           Order\
               OrderIndex.aspx
           Transfer\
               TransferIndex.aspx
```

What I would like to do is simply the number of folders to do something like this:

```
Areas\
   Orders\
       Controllers\
           OrderController.cs   (Action method: Index, OrderIndex, TransferIndex)
       Views\
           Index.aspx
           OrderIndex.aspx
           TransferIndex.aspx
```

Is this possible? Is this a routing setup?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom view engine. I will provide an example with Razor:

```
public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public MyViewEngine()
    {
        base.AreaViewLocationFormats = base.AreaViewLocationFormats.Union(new[] 
        {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}{0}.cshtml"    
        }).ToArray();
    }
}
```

and then register this view engine in `Application_Start`:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyViewEngine());
```

and that's pretty much all you're gonna need to achieve what you are looking for.

And of course if you are using the WebForms view engine slight adaptations are necessary:

```
public class MyViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine
{
    public MyViewEngine()
    {
        base.AreaViewLocationFormats = base.AreaViewLocationFormats.Union(new[] 
        {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}{0}.aspx"
        }).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to give my architecture some more thought and will file this as a possible way to go.